# Quartz 2.2.X and Spring 4 integration

Tags: java, spring, integration, quartz-scheduler

I try to integrate Quartz scheduler with Spring Framweork 4, but I have following problem:

```
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist
  Position: 15
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1761)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1531)
    ... 38 more
```

Obviously quartz ignore my `quartz.properties` file, placed in classpath, where is defined jobStore RAM. Does anyone have an idea, why is Quartz always tries create database tables?

**quartz.properties**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=1
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

**applicationContext-scheduling.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
     default-autowire="byName"
    >


   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties"/>
        <property name="startupDelay" value="15"/>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
             <ref bean="sendAlertEmailsCronTrigger"/> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean name="sendAlertEmailsJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="cz.nlfnorm.scheduling.SendAlertEmailsJob" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Triggers -->
    <bean name="sendAlertEmailsCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="sendAlertEmailsJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/3 * 1/1 * ? *" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

*Spring Framework 4.0.5, 
Quartz 2.2.1, 
Apache Tomcat 7*

Comment: Have you tried to enable logging for the SchedulerFactoryBean class? When SchedulerFactoryBean loads the Quartz config resource, it logs the following INFO message: "Loading Quartz config from [" + this.configLocation + "]".

If you do not really have to use quartz.properties, try setting the Quartz configuration properties using the SchedulerFactoryBean's quartzProperties property. This always worked for me.